# Detect if user is scrolling within a div

Tags: html, angularjs, scroll

I searched for a way to detect if a user is scrolling within a div with `angularjs`. I looked on their documentation (https://docs.angularjs.org/api?PHPSESSID=cae8e98e7ca559b4605d75c813b358ee) and searched something like `ng-click`, but I didn't find anything regarding scrolling there. Is there really no easy way to do this? I would like to do something like this:

```
<div ng-scroll="ctrl.doSomething()">
</div>
```

I know, ng-scroll doesn't really exist. I just wrote it as an example. Any ideas to do this WITHOUT any external plugins or directives that I have to include?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can make your own custome directive like:

```
.directive("ngScroll", function ($window) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {

        angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
            console.log('do something!'); 
            scope.$apply();
        });
    };
});
```

and use it like this:

```
<div ng-scroll>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, this seems to be a nice alternative solution, I will try it and tell you if it works. Thanks!